# SignalrR HubConnection disregards query parameter

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I want to allow my users connect to a specific group in my SignalR hub, to do this i generate a unique id that the users in that group can share with others. Once a user connects to the hub, the id is generated. On the "connected" event their URL updates with the unique id. When I then use the URL to join the newly created room it seems like two negotiation requests are sent, both containing the the group id as well as the users connection id, yet sometimes(not always) I get a response from the Hub containing a newly generated Group.

Is the `?pod` parameter I pass into the url not always assigned before the request is made?

To me it seems completely random, but it's most likely some error I've made in my connection code since I'm relatively new to Angular.

This request happened correctly and I joined the room I wanted.

[Correct behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqN6w.jpg)

This one happened incorrectly and a new room was generated even though, seemingly(?), the request looks the same, save for the web socket connection containing the "pid".

[Incorrect behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8lVd.jpg)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**The code for the Home component where the connection is initiated**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

  welcomeMessage:string;

  podId:string;
  users:User[];

  constructor(private signalrService: SignalRService, private  http: HttpClient, private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router, private location: Location) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.podId = params['pod'];
      this.connectToPod();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  }

  connectToPod(){
    this.signalrService.startConnection(this.podId);
    this.signalrService.addPodConnectedLisener((data: Pod) => {

      this.podId = data.id;
      this.users = data.users;

      this.location.replaceState('/?pod=' + this.podId)
      this.welcomeMessage = window.location.origin + '/?pod=' + this.podId;
    });
  }
}
```

**The code for the SignalR service**

```
export class SignalRService {

  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
  private baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor() { }

  public startConnection (podId?: string) {

    let idToSend = podId == undefined ? '' : '?pid=' + podId;

    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                              .withUrl(this.baseUrl + '/pod' + idToSend)
                              .build();

    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err));
  }

  public addPodConnectedLisener (connectedCallback: Function) {
    return this.hubConnection.on('connected', data => {
      connectedCallback(data);
    });
  }
}
```

**The code for the SignalR Hub**

```
    public class PodHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly IPodConnectionManger _podConnectionManager;

        public PodHub(IPodConnectionManger podConnectionManager)
        {
            _podConnectionManager = podConnectionManager;
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var podId = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["pid"].ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(podId))
            {
                await CreatePod();
            }
            else
            {
                await JoinPod(podId);
            }
        }

        private async Task CreatePod()
        {
            var newPodId = await _podConnectionManager.AddPod();
            var podToSend = await _podConnectionManager.GetPod(newPodId);

            await podToSend.AddUser(Context.ConnectionId);
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, podToSend.Id);
            await Clients.Group(podToSend.Id).SendAsync("connected", podToSend);
        }

        private async Task JoinPod(string id)
        {
            var podToJoin = await _podConnectionManager.GetPod(id);

            await podToJoin.AddUser(Context.ConnectionId);
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, podToJoin.Id);
            await Clients.Group(podToJoin.Id).SendAsync("connected", podToJoin);
        }
}
```